# Powershell Invoke-Command Function within a Script

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script file called "ExecutBizTalkAppMSI.ps1" This contains a single function called "Install-BizTalkApplication". I need to execute the function on a remote server, so I use the "Invoke-Command" cmdlet as follows:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer $TargetServer -FilePath .\ExecuteBizTalkAppMSI.ps1 -argumentlist $MSI, $InstallFolderOnTargetServer, $Environment
```

Problem is, although the target script runs (I added a Write-Host directly after the Param() section), the function "Install-BizTalkApplication" is not executed.

Can anyone please let me know what I need to do to make this happen?

Comment: You probably will need to share some actual code to get help in troubleshooting this.

Comment: I'm not so sure - I just need to know if it's possible to execute a function within a script using the Invoke-Command cmdlet. If not, then what does the target script need to look like - how does it know which function to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the script looks like that:

```
# start
function Foo {}
# end
```

That won't work. Two options:

- get rid of function name {} and run script *as is*
- define a function first, and run it as last step in a script

Example:

```
# script 1
param ($foo, $bar)
# function body...

# script 2
param ($foo, $bar)
function foo {
param ($foo, $bar)
# function body
}

foo -foo $foo -bar $bar
```

Comment: Thanks Bartek that worked. Since I only have a single function contained within the script file, I decided to remove the function{}

Answer (score 0):

You say it "contains a function called"...  So, if you run that script on your local machine with those arguments.. i.e:

```
.\ExecuteBizTalkAppMSI.ps1 $MSI $InstallFolderOnTargetServer $Environment
```

It wouldn't work, because you're running a script which just loads a function, and then stops, correct?  That's your problem.

If so, you'll need to add a param statement to the top of the script, before the function:

```
param($MSI, $InstallFolderOnTargerServer, $Environment)
```

And then at the bottom, outside of the function you'll have to add:

```
Install-BizTalkApplication $MSI $InstallFolderonTarget $Environment
```

This will allow the script to accept arguments, and then pass those arguments to a statement that calls the function.